# Можно ли в php поставить "указатель" на участок памяти?

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Я сохраняю в memcache значение. Можно ли, как только оно изменится, выполнить скрипт.

На данный момент у меня получается в скрипте бесконечный цикл, который проверяет значение и засыпает на некоторое время, но он использует процесс + делает проверки, а хотелось бы, как только изменилось значение, выполнить функцию скрипта, а не каждый раз проверять.

Такое возможно?

Спасибо.

Comment: > как только изменилось значение

Любое значение или по конкретному ключу?

Comment: по определённому ключу

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, если не ошибаюсь, у Вас демон? Можно попробовать так:

Данные в виде массива с дополнительным флагом.

    $data = [
      'value' => 'message text',
      'change' => 1 // сообщение изменилось
    ];

Ваш демон:

    $memcache = new Memcache;
    while(true) {
       if (($result = $memcache->get('key')) !== false && $result['change']) {
    
          /* некие действия с $result */
    
          $result['change'] = 0;
          $memcache->set('key', $result);
       }
    }

Comment: @Роман Ракзин Но вообще, для этого используют MQ-сервисы ([RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), [Gearman](http://goo.gl/INjkjJ),...). Две очереди на запись и чтение. Ниже в ответе Вам об этом написали.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, Memcached - это отдельное приложение, с отдельной памятью.
Так как у нас в ОС существует понятие виртуальная память, то в него ты никак не попадешь.

1 Вариант (если один и тот же скрипт):
Существует подход к синхронизации, событийный.
Читай в Интернете про Event Manager.

Советую взять из Symfony 2/Zend 2 (притянуть только 1 компоненты через Composer).

2 Вариант (если 2 разных скрипта):
Читай про очереди
Gearman/Beanstalkd